# Exporting more than 1 layer to GDB file type

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase

Is there any way in QGIS to export more than 1 file layer/type to GDB?

The only way I can see is to right-click the particular layer and save as GDB file type, but that only allow individual layers to be exported instead of multiple layers in 1 single GDB file.

The only way I know is to install a spatial database and export it from that, but that isn't an option in my case.

Comment: As far as I know there isn't possible to do that. I have been looking for it so many times.